# DISTCP to GCS behind PROXY

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-platform, distcp

I am trying to use distcp to copy some files from HDFS to Amazon gcs. My Hadoop cluster connects to the internet through an HTTP proxy, but I can't figure out how to specify this when connecting to gcs.

Any documentation about this topic ?

Comment: I am trying to use distcp to copy some files from HDFS to Google Cloud Storage and not amazone.

Answer (score 0):

Links to my question but still not enough:

1. https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/distcp-proxy-settings.html
2. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/commit/bc8f6c6dc9aa7c5586376e830c3dbec0427fa815

The second link add's the `fs.gs.proxy.address` but nothing related to Proxy USER and Password.

Comment: Proxy authentication support was added in [GCS connector 1.9.8](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/releases/tag/v1.9.8) through `fs.gs.proxy.username` and `fs.gs.proxy.password` properties.

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster is already connected to the Internet through a proxy, then you can connect to GCS if you install the [Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/install-storage-connector#steps_to_install_the_connector). At the end, you have to be able to execute commands like:

```
hadoop fs -ls gs://my-bucket-datalake

hadoop fs -cp /hadoop/datalake gs://my-bucket-datalake

hadoop distcp hdfs://<LOCAL_NN>:8020/foo/bar gs://my-bucket-datalake
```

Hope it helps!